# Comparing Action.Method of a stored method and a method of a passed method parameter results in false though they are the same

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, delegates

Im trying to learn something about delegates, actions etc. Im trying to make a script, that makes the methods from other scripts only activate once, if you pass the method as a parameter, and cant be activated again, if you pass the same method as a parameter again. To store the methods from other scripts, im using a List of Actions (Im making it like that, so I can compare a stored method with a passed method and see, if it was already activated). The comparing between a passed method and a stored method only results in false in `resetMethod()` , because the Action.Method of both is different even though they are the same. `Debug.Log()` says

```
Void <Jump>b__15_0()
Void <Move>b__14_1()
```

How do I fix it?

```
public class CallMethodOnce : MonoBehaviour
{
    public class Method
    {
        public Action method {get;}
        public bool called {get; set;}

        public Method(Action method, bool called = false)
        {
            this.method = method;
        }
    }

    List<Method> methods = new List<Method>();


    public void callMethodOnce(Action method)
    {

        Method _method = new Method(method);
        Method methodToCall = null;
        
        if (methods.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < methods.Count; i++)
            {
  
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(_method.method, methods[i].method))
                {
                    methodToCall = methods[i];
                    methods.Remove(_method);
                }
                else
                {
                    methods.Add(_method);
                    methodToCall = _method;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            methods.Add(_method);
            methodToCall = _method;
        }
        
        Debug.Log(methodCalled(methodToCall));

        if (methodCalled(methodToCall)) return;

        methodToCall.method();
        methodToCall.called = true;
    }

    public void resetMethod(Action method)
    {
        foreach(Method m in methods)
        {
            Debug.Log(method.Method + "\n" + m.method.Method);
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(method, m.method))
            {
                Debug.Log("reseted");
                m.called = false;
            }
        }
    }

    bool methodCalled(Method method)
    {
        return method.called;
    }
}
```

Here are the only parts the script is used
in. This

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded)
   {
       timerCreater.SetTimer(0.25f, () => Jump());
       onceMethodCaller.callMethodOnce(() => 
       AnimationParameterController.ChangeParameter(AnimationParameterController.jumped, true));
      return;
    }
```

and this

```
void Jump()
    {
        if (!isGrounded) return;
        ySpeed = jumpHeight;
        playerRb.velocity += new Vector3(0, ySpeed, 0);
        onceMethodCaller.resetMethod(() => AnimationParameterController.ChangeParameter(AnimationParameterController.jumped, true));
    }
```

Comment: You are creating new instance `Method _method = new Method(method);` and comparing with other instance `if (object.ReferenceEquals(_method.method, methods[i].method))` in your `callMethodOnce()`, it will never return true because they are two difference instances, they are not same

Answer (score 0):

`Delegate.ReferenceEquals()` did the job for me.